# Does the Whitehead torsion of a homotopy equivalence depend on the CW structure?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, algebraic-k-theory

In the (old) literature I've seen referenced the question of whether simple homotopy equivalence is a topological property, i.e. whether it depends only on the underlying space, rather than the decomposition. I believe this has been answered affirmatively, at least for polyhedra (essentially realizations of finite simplicial complexes), since in this case it has been shown that a map with contractible point inverses is simple, and surely a homeomorphism has contractible point inverses.

However, this still leaves open the question of whether the torsion of a non-homeomorphism depends on the CW structure. Is it known one way or the other?

Comment: This is a theorem of Chapman, known as Topological Invariance of Whitehead Torsion.

Comment: Thanks Tom, and of course this is enough because if I have a homotopy equivalence $X \rightarrow Y$ and have two CW structures on $X$, call them $X',X"$, I can consider $X' \rightarrow Y \rightarrow X''$ which is homotopic to the identity which by your reference has 0 torsion. So we deduce that the Whitehead torsion does not depend on the CW structure for any homotopy equivalence.

Comment: And let me hazard a comment that might be helpful to others, Chapman's proof works by showing that being a simple homotopy equivalence is equivalent to having the result of crossing the map with an infinite dimensional manifold being homotopic to a homeomorphism. To me this makes it more clear why categories of simple homotopy equivalences could be related to things like stable h-cobordism spaces when simple homotopy equivalence is something which seems very much unstable.

Comment: And let me add that the "infinite-dimensional manifolds" in question are the compact spaces locally homeomorphic to the "Hilbert cube"--the product of an infinite sequence of closed intervals.